# Looking for a small level OOPS design questions

Tags: java, oop

Trying to improve my OOPS skills. Is there a site or book where can I find OOPS problems like CoffeeBrewerDesign problem? Or somebody can give me some problems on which I can work?

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040011/oops-concept-java

Comment: dint understand tht. I thot tht was a dumb question. ny ABC's of java book wld hve answered those questions.

Comment: there are some references there! Check this too   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926542/looking-for-a-small-level-oops-design-questions

Comment: Can you problem a link to the Coffee Brewer Design problem, and use English in your comments?

Comment: @MozenRath did you mean to link the this question to itself?

Comment: :) sorry peter. I am used to texting in the mobile. So typed in tht mode. will keep it in proper english

Answer (score 3):

I personally have this book and I find it pretty well written and easy to read.  They give you specific problems that you need to solve and show you different ways of solving them.

[Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this book: http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/oodesign.html

In general it is recommended not only reading books but apply knowledge in practice.

Comment: thts rite.I m currently reading the Roullette example given in the book.Its amazing. Searching for problems where the knowledge can be applied